# Slow loading of text in WYSIWYG with TinyMCE 3.5 in Chrome Browser

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

On an node edit page with WYSIWYG (TinyMCE) it takes over a second for the text to show up, see this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0bMlmBJls9E).

FireFox doesn't seem to have this issue.
Has anyone chrome across this?

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you using? I'm using build 18.0.1025.168 and I don't get the same delay with TinyMCE on a local dev site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turned out to be an issue with CSS_Injector module, [this](http://drupal.org/node/1485444#comment-5958910) is the fix.